# Restarting drag immediately after stopDrag

Tags: javascript, konvajs

I want to limit how much one can drag my layer. To do this, I use stopDrag inside dragBoundFunc, as in the following code.

How can I reenable dragging immediately after stopping?

I tried  with setTimeout with no luck, I get the layer to be draggable again only after clicking on some object inside it.

```
this.layer = new Konva.Layer({draggable : true});

function myPosition() {
     ...
}

var that = this;
this.layer.dragBoundFunc( 
    function(pos) {
        var y = pos.y;
        if (y + myPosition()<0) {
            this.stopDrag();
            setTimeout(function() {that.layer.startDrag();}, 30);
        }
        if (y+myPosition()>50) {
            this.stopDrag();
            setTimeout(function() {that.layer.startDrag();}, 30);
        }               
        return {
            x : this.getAbsolutePosition().x,
            y : y
        };
    });
```

Comment: The dragBoundsFunc() can be used to stop the user dragging - you would not normally need to apply stopDrag(). Instead just return the x,y you want the layer to have. See [this example](https://konvajs.github.io/docs/drag_and_drop/Simple_Drag_Bounds.html)

Comment: Thank you, I know that but I'd like using stopDrag because it's difficult to calculate the correct position of y

Comment: @cdarwin why do you need to start drag again? Why do you stop it?

Comment: I need to start drag again because when I stopped drag I limited the dragging in one direction (up or down), but then a user could drag in the opposite direction which is allowed (if the user is at layer.y=0, he is stopped, but then he could move at layer.y>0 which is allowed). I stop dragging because the user has reached a limit such as y=0. I don't use setting y because it's difficult to calculate it based on other parameters